# Creating a default custom message for Zod .or validation

Tags: zod

I have such rules defined in Zod

```
PersonClientPersonReference.or(PersonSystemPersonReference)
  .or(PersonInitial)
  .or(PersonFirstName)
  .or(PersonSurname)
  .or(PersonPreferredName)
```

I want to have a single custom message when doing safeParse validation rather than having a message that is split by OR. All above like PersonInitial, PersonFirstName as Zod.object with different number of items.